# How to format these checkboxes for equal spacing using only HTML or little CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox, formatting

**How to format these checkboxes for equal spacing using only HTML or little CSS.**
I'm having difficulty adding spacing between the checkboxes even though I have them in a different row they don't seem to be cooperating.

```
<fieldset>
        <legend><h2><b><u>General Information</u></b></h2></legend>  
        <table cellpadding="8">
            <th>I would like more information abput the followng users:-</th>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">Backpack Cal</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">California Hotspring</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">California Cabin</td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">Cycle California</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">Kids California</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">From Desert To Sea</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">Nature Watch</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">Taste Of California</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">Snow Board Cali</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *colspan* attribute for the *th* element to span the entire column

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <fieldset>
        <legend><h2><b><u>General Information</u></b></h2></legend>  
        <table cellpadding="8">
            <th colspan="3">I would like more information about the followng users:-</th>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">Backpack Cal</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">California Hotspring</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">California Cabin</td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">Cycle California</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">Kids California</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">From Desert To Sea</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">Nature Watch</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">Taste Of California</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="user">Snow Board Cali</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

This will give almost an equal spacing for *input* element

Answer (score 0):

**Try it.. It may works!**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>checkbox</title>
    <style>
        .check
        {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: left;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        div.check div
        {
            width:160px;
            margin:10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h2><b><u>General Information</u></b></h2></legend>  
        <h3>I would like more information about the followng users:-</h3>
        <div class="check">
                <div><input type="checkbox" name="user">Backpack Cal</div>        
                <div><input type="checkbox" name="user">California Hotspring</div> 
                <div><input type="checkbox" name="user">California Cabin</div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" name="user">Cycle California</div>            
                <div><input type="checkbox" name="user">Kids California</div>           
                <div><input type="checkbox" name="user">From Desert To Sea</div>              
                <div><input type="checkbox" name="user">Nature Watch</div>        
                <div><input type="checkbox" name="user">Taste Of California</div>               
                <div><input type="checkbox" name="user">Snow Board Cali</div>  
            </div>
     </fieldset>   
</body>
</html>
```